# If two points have the same stereographic projection, does that imply that the points are the same?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not working on a specific problem, I have just been learning about stereographic projections and was wondering if this was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Stereographic projection is one-to-one.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to say why rather than just claim the result.

Comment: @Integrand I said why: because it's one-to-one. I don't think I'm going to repeat the exact definition of the projection and a complete derivation of all its properties here. The stereographic projection is well known and described in dozens, if not hundreds, web pages. It's enough to look at Wikipedia to find _'the mapping is smooth and bijective'_ in the leading paragraph. Anyway, the question was **'is it?'**, not **'give me a proof'**. So I answered the question: yes,  it is. Period. If anything else was needed, let OP enhance the question.